# Google Glass Heating

Tags: android, google-glass, gdk

I am having hard time developing apps for Google Glass.  I have very simple app that uses Scandit bar code reader... The glass heats > 30 degrees in 5 minutes and becomes unresponsive.  Anybody else encountered such a problem?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like there may be a memory leak somewhere. You can try putting in some Log statements to see if anything is repeating / looks strange. Also, please post some code as well

Comment: Is Glass plugged in by USB?  This leads to charging and heat increase.  You can try to do the same thing unplugged and see if it helps.  Can you make it more clear what the behavior of Glass is without your app installed in same conditions (plugged in or not)?  If the temperature increase only happens with your app installed, you could have an infinite loop or similar.  I assume this is what you are seeing: https://plus.google.com/+JasonSalas/posts/NncfeaPkb9W ... I have encountered the problem in early GDK days on XE12, and when plugged in.  I agree with MJ93, please post code.

Comment: Its a common thing. I got that problem too with developing AR applications and OCR scanning. Glass is just not suited for complex computing for now.

Answer (score 4):

Heating is a common problem for Glass.

Heavy computations (computer vision, video processing, barcode recognition, augmented reality) lead to significant heat.

In order to minimize impact of heat, try replacing your real-time camera barcode scanning with processing of a single image, taken with the camera.

BTW, there's a great article, which describes battery drain and heat issue from scientific point of view.

[`Draining our Glass: An Energy and Heat Characterization of Google Glass`](http://www.ruf.rice.edu/~mobile/publications/likamwa2014glass.pdf)

A little abstract from the article:

> > ... (2) high-power processing leads
> >     to signiﬁcant heat, which should be limited, due to the Glass’
> >     compact form factor and close proximity to the user’s skin